# converting from mysql_ to PDO php Error

Tags: php, pdo

Just converting from mysql_ to PDO. An of course getting some errors.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include("php/connect.php");

if ($_POST['submit']){

    $username = $db -> prepare($_POST['username']);
    $password = $db -> prepare($_POST['password']);

    if($username){

        if($password){

            $password = md5(md5("KmsdufIFNKSnefndbdo19228330293".$password."JSDSHBFJS8S8ds8sd8s8d"));
            $query = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'");             
            $num_rows = $db -> rowCount($query);

            if ($num_rows == 1){

                $row = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $db_username = $row['username'];
                $db_password = $row['password'];

                if ($password == $db_password){

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                }else
                    $div = "<div id='error'>Passwordi eshte gabim</div>";

            }else
                $div = "<div id='error'>Emri nuk u gjend</div>";

        }else
            $div = "<div id='error'>Futeni Passwordin</div>";

    }else
        $div= "<div id='error'>Futeni emrin e llogarise</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: WHYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY VOTE DOWNNNN WHYYYYYYYYY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pdo::prepare](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) is not a replacement for [mysql_real_escape_string](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). It parses an sql statement (or lets the underlying database system do that work, see [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.attr-emulate-prepares)), looking for placeholders which are replaced by actual parameters when the statement is executed.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?');
// $stmt now "is" the identifier for the previously prepared statement
// it can be executed but needs one parameter to fill out the placeholder
$stmt->execute( array($_POST['username']) );
// it could be executed again with another parameter
// $stmt->execute( array('Foo') );
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ( !$row ) {
    // no such user
}
else {
    ....
```

see also:

- http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements
- http://wezfurlong.org/images/PDO.pdf

Comment: Thanks my friend. Now i get it. Thanks for the documents as well

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `prepare` method (http://de3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). You're wrong. You have do insert your statement in there. 
And: please use prepared statements, not direct (unsanitized) variable input.

I think, the PHP Manual is a good starting point.

Comment: like this --> $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?";
            $exec = $db -> prepare($query);
            $exec -> execute(array($username));

Comment: Yes, exactly. Go like this.

Comment: Thanks bro .. i figured it out using @VolkerK help and yours

Answer (score 0):

The format you need to use for PDO (based on what you are trying to do) is:

```
$sql = 'SELECT query here .......';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($result) {
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Can you tick it as the answer then please :)